# Create Event in Saleforce Database programatically using jquery mobile

Tags: html5, jquerymobile, salesforcetouchplatform

I successful pull Events from salesforce database and display in UI, but my further task is to create Events from my application, i.e, hybrid app, written in html5 and jquery-mobile for mobile devices like iPhone and Android and also  and result shown in database also. Is there any way to do this.

Thanks in advance. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this like

```
var locationValue = "Sector ABC";
var whatid = "00097438q44";
var sub = "This is test subject";
var whoid = "f4r634o43985";
var ownercreatedid = "65476597354";
var start = "2013-08-07T00:00:00.000+0000";
var end = "2013-08-07T00:00:00.000+0000";

forcetkClient.create('Event',{
                     "WhatId" : whatid,
                     "Location" : locationValue,
                     "WhoId" : whoid,
                     "OwnerId" : ownercreatedid,
                     "Subject" : sub,
                     "EndDateTime" : end,
                     "StartDateTime" : start


                     },function(record){
                     console.log("Create record Sucessfully");

                     },onErrorSfdc);
```

where Location,Subject etc are database fields.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-JavaScript-REST-Toolkit/blob/master/forcetk.js

Use the forcetk library to do this if you have an HTML5 page for your app on your device  .Use the create call to create an event .

```
/*
 * Creates a new record of the given type.
 * @param objtype object type; e.g. "Account"
 * @param fields an object containing initial field names and values for 
 *               the record, e.g. {:Name "salesforce.com", :TickerSymbol 
 *               "CRM"}
 * @param callback function to which response will be passed
 * @param [error=null] function to which jqXHR will be passed in case of error
 */
forcetk.Client.prototype.create = function(objtype, fields, callback, error) {
    return this.ajax('/' + this.apiVersion + '/sobjects/' + objtype + '/'
    , callback, error, "POST", JSON.stringify(fields));
}
```

If you have option of using visualforce for the app then you can use RemoteAction or you can directly make a call in API version 28.0 using jquery

http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2013/06/calling-the-force-com-rest-api-from-visualforce-pages-revisited.html

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Developing_Hybrid_Apps_with_the_Salesforce_Mobile_SDK

```
 forcetkClient.create('ContentVersion', {
    "PathOnClient" : name + ".png",
    "VersionData" : imageData
}, function(data){
    // Now update the Contact record with the new ContentVersion Id
    SFHybridApp.logToConsole('Created ContentVersion ' + data.id);
    forcetkClient.update('Contact', contactId, { 
        "Image_ID__c" : data.id 
    }, function(){
        $j.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
        SFHybridApp.logToConsole('Updated Contact '+contactId);
    }, onErrorSfdc);
}, onErrorSfdc);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Mohith, but I am not able to implement this query to my application. Is there any example available. There is a great help.

Comment: http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Developing_Hybrid_Apps_with_the_Salesforce_Mobile_SDK                                     Please go through the following link and you can explore on how to build a sample html5 app with forceTK .

Comment: Thanks Mohith, that I know the way to create hybrid app, but my concern is to how I create a record in Salesforce ,i.e, ceate an Event.

Comment: In the contact explorer app just examine how the code is written to create attachment in sfdc.Same way just you need to use to create events.I can draft a code but in my free time and show you how it works

Comment: Thank you so much Mohith, I will see the code Contact explorer.

Comment: I edited my answer to add some code from that app on how to create record in sfdc

Comment: Thanks Mohith, it will great help but please tell me why you use create and then update query for two diffrent table.

Comment: Cool!Please post as answer or upvote if my answer helped ?

Answer (score 0):

See [Force.com REST API Developer's Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/), under Using REST Resources > Using REST API Resources > Working with Records > Create a record. In short, you use your already-acquired session ID, and submit some JSON to the specified address using jQuery's `ajax()` function.

Comment: This is not exactly what I want. Thanks for your help, If there is any example available please send a link to me.